# Check if .match() result is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I run this regex `.match()`:

```
var pattern = /property="og:description"\scontent="(.+?)"/;   
var matches = data.match(pattern);
    
if (matches[1]) {
   var = description = matches[1];
}
```

But occasionally, I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: matches is null
```

What can I do to check if `matches[1]` is not empty?

#### What I've tried so far

I tried this:

```
if (matches && matches[1]) {
```

And

```
if (matches.length && matches[1].length) {
```

And

```
if (matches[1] != null) {
```

And

```
if (matches[1] != undefined && matches[1] != null) {
```

Still getting this error occasionally. Clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: I think there is a syntax error if this is from the full example. You are assigning var which is a reserved word. Could it be the cause? Otherwise there is no problem with how you check it in the first try example you have given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `[1]` from `matches` when you check it has a value. The error is because you're trying to access a null value by index.

```js
let pattern = /property="og:description"\scontent="(.+?)"/;   

['foobar', 'property="og:description" content="abc"'].forEach(data => {
   let matches = data.match(pattern);
   let description = 'no match';
   if (matches) 
    description = matches[1];
    
   console.log(description);   
});
```

Comment: But in theory, wouldn't `matches && matches[1]` work as well?

Comment: This is not true actually if you access the matches && matches[1] you can still execute the same condition. If you try it this code will succeed.

Comment: You're correct - my bad. The first match, if there are any, is the full matching string. So yes, `matches && match[1]` would work too. I've updated the answer to provide both match/no match logic